# What happens if a Beholder places its Antimagic Cone on a target that has been affected by its eye rays?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, magic, antimagic-field

What happens if a Beholder places its Antimagic Cone over someone it has hit with its eye rays?  Obviously the damage-dealing ones are instantaneous, but what about the charm ray, petrification ray, paralyze ray, sleep ray...etc.?

Comment: I want to believe that the beholder could use its antimagic cone to temporarily un-petrify a creature petrified by its eye ray, if only because I think the beholder would get a lot of entertainment out of it.

Answer (score 8):

### The effects of all rays with ongoing effects are suppressed.

From Antimagic Field (Which is the effect caused by Antimagic Cone):

> Spells and other **magical effects**, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed...

From the beholder:

> The beholder shoots three of the following **magical** eye rays at random...

All effects of the eye rays are magical, so they would be suppressed. To be clear, "suppressed" in this context means that those effects disappear inside the area of effect, but aren't removed. They will return as soon as the area is left.

Comment: Does AMF, then, cure petrification in general?  Is that how it works?

Comment: @Stackstuck It doesn't cure petrification, but assuming the source is magical, it would suppress it. So the creature would be unpetrified only for as long as it remained within the anti-magic field. Edited the answer to clarify this a bit.

Comment: @AgentPaper no, it won’t - changing someone to stone (and back) is magical but once you are stone there is no ongoing magical effect

Comment: I like this answer, but the "**all** rays" part is probably why it's drawing downvotes, and discouraging me from voting either way. If you could address DaleM's comment, that would likely improve your answer.

Comment: @NathanS I don't think "all rays" is incorrect, the rays and thus their effects are explicitly magical, so anything that suppresses magic would suppress all of them.

Comment: @DaleM As it happens, since I think there's a lot to unpack here, I've actually just asked [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150188/35259) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150189/35259) relating to petrification vs. _antimagic field_.